# How to install new font in RStudio?

Tags: macos, fonts, rstudio

I want to install a new font in RStudio.
More specifically, I use RStudio in my office (Windows) and at home (OS X), but I see that the fonts are different and takes me a while to get used to that.

**Can someone suggest how to install SAS monospace font in RStudio in Mac?**
*(I did a search here and in Google but I had no luck finding an answer to my question.)*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I ran into similar issue on Windows I wanted to use a new font I installed, mononoki font.  I could not find an option to change so I look at RStudio source code and discovered that for Desktop Version of RStudio, RStudio automatically loads fonts from the OS. It should work the same way on MAC.

All you have to do is:

```
1.Install your font as usual for your OS
2.Then restart RStudio
3.The new font appears in the Editor Fonts pull down menu 
   (navigation: Global Options -->Appearance --> Editor Fonts)
4.Select the font from Editor Fonts pulldown menu.(Your Done!)
```

Here is the [code](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/ebb054efe3e650de818a251b11087311e5169ed8/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/core/client/theme/ThemeFonts.java) which loads the fonts from RStudio. As you can see it automatically loads proportional and fixed fonts.  The Web Version of RStudio restricts the font selection to only a few fonts.

```
 static class DesktopThemeFontLoader implements ThemeFontLoader
   {
      public native final String getProportionalFont() /*-{
         return $wnd.desktop.proportionalFont();
      }-*/;

      public native final String getFixedWidthFont() /*-{
         return $wnd.desktop.fixedWidthFont();
      }-*/;
   }
```